# Using SD card as internal storage and migrate date

Tags: external-sd, 6.0-marshmallow, storage, app2sd, adoptable-storage

I read [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81858/insufficient-space-on-the-device-but-my-sd-card-has-plenty-space), but I want to update the question.

Now with Android 6.0 we have the option to format the SD card as internal storage, and that's what I did. I also clicked that "Migrate data" option that moves pictures, music and such to the SD card storage.

[image: Storage]

However, I downloaded more music and now the internal storage is full. **And the "Migrate data" option now tries to move data from the SD to the internal memory.** So apparently you can only use it once #fail

**The apps that consume the most space are precisely apps containing media that could go into the SD card** (red arrows). Others are games that even allow the user to move the app to the SD card (blue arrow). For some weird reason, it always fails with a snack bar saying "internal error occurred".

[image: Biggest apps]

- Should I format the SD card as external? I'll never remove it, so this "format as internal memory" option seemed perfect.
- How can I migrate all this media/data back to the SD card?

Am I doing something wrong here? I have a Moto G 2nd gen.

Comment: Im pretty sure you can go into google play music, head to settings, and set your sd as storage. It should move your music over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think I found out the best setup.

1. Format your SD card as internal memory.
2. Go to **Settings > Storage > Internal** and open each app. Some apps have a "change" button. Press it to move the app into the SD card.
3. Finally go to **Settings > Storage > Internal** and on the right corner press **Migrate data**.

At this point, you did all you could.

Comment: For some reason, not at apps offer this option. Any idea why?

Comment: @DiAlex, I am doing one app where data need to move the datas from internal storage to external storage while transfer the app. But it is unable to move the data. I have followed your suggestions. But I am unable to see the third point for migration of data. Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to solve it. I'm using Android 6.0 on a Moto G (2nd gen) and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to format the SD as removable storage for it to work as you describe. The option as described by Dan is not available with your SD formatted for internal use.

I did read a post somewhere that suggests Google Play Music will have a fix this week but hard to say for sure.

In my opinion this feature either doesn't work as intended or the Google Play apps haven't been updated for this feature despite marshmallow being out for 6? months already.

Note: I have just installed the new update 22/4/2016 and you can now select the SD storage, so this is now fixed!

Comment: Thanks. But before I can format the SD card I need to move all of its contents back to internal storage, otherwise I'll lose data. However, I don't have enough space, and we're back at the OP :(